# Resolving linking issues on Rust / C++ interop

Tags: c++, rust

When using a Rust function from C++, how do you actually link them together? I have created a minimal case which works perfectly well for C++/C interop but does not when replacing the C object file with a rust staticlib:

main.cpp:

```cpp
#include<cstdio>

extern "C" void hello();

int main() {
  puts("Hello from C++");
  hello();
}
```

helper.rs:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn hello() {
    println!("Hello from Rust")
}
```

Commands executed (+ error):

```bash
g++ -c main.cpp # creates main.o
rustc --crate-type staticlib helper.rs # creates libhelper.a
g++ libhelper.a main.o # fails with error below
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `hello'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have checked with `nm` that libhelper.a actually contains hello (`T hello`) and that main.o has hello as undefined symbol (`U hello`). What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, when linking against a static library, it is not inserted as a whole in the executable.
The missing symbols referenced by the `.o` files are searched in the library, and only the module which provides this symbol is inserted in the executable.
(A static library is generally an archive of modules, i.e. `.o` files).

In this search, the order is important.
If `libhelper.a` is considered before `main.o`, then nothing in this library seems to be useful.
But afterwards, when `main.o` is considered, the required symbol is still missing.

In general, it is better to enumerate all the `.o` files first, then all the static libraries after.

Here, simply use:

```
g++ main.o libhelper.a
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/11527076).